# Is there a single noun, preferably not a gerund, for the act of exceeding or surpassing?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a single noun, preferably not a gerund, for the act of exceeding or surpassing? In editing test reports and similar technical material, I come across the notion of exceeding or surpassing a limit, threshold, or expectation. My dictionary searches have yielded only gerunds. I've considered "exceedance" but cannot find evidence that it is a word.

Comment: Can you give an example (with a blank is fine) for the gerund-free sentence you hope to construct?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is "overtop", and only because it's such a hodgepodge of a word that it might slip past your requirements.

Comment: here's some proof for exceedance http://www.onelook.com/?w=exceedance&ls=a

Comment: I'm not sure *exceedance* means what Debby intends.  It seems as though *exceedance* is the thing that is in excess, rather than the actual act of exceeding (something more like *excession, perhaps).

Comment: You mean, like stackoverflow?

Comment: @Kit: *exceedance* definitely isn't what OP intends. It's a somewhat geeky bit of bureaucratese meaning the amount by which some measurement (of a pollutant, for example) exceeds an ideal/recommended/legal limit.

Comment: Sample usage(?): The moment of ___ came when the tortoise passed the hare, who was fast asleep under a shady tree.

Comment: @Kit/FumbleFingers: exceedance can be the amount by which something exceeded something else or it can be the event (act) of exceeding (http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/exceedance.html , http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exceedance ). From these definitions it seems to be *exactly* what OP intends, don't you agree?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, also when I am not sure about usage, I try to search to books and sample the actual usage. If you do that http://www.google.com/search?q=%22exceedance%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en#q=%22exceedance%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=VbT5TYjnJYqBOsfbjbQE&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=4145421307f4e362&biw=1213&bih=820 I believe you will find "test reports and similar technical material, with notion of exceeding or surpassing a limit, threshold, or expectation" as OP intended.

Comment: @Unreason: OP's 'synonyms' for the target word are *exceeding* and *surpassing*, which to my mind suggests "being better". As implied, I don't think much of *exceedance/exceedence* as words in the first place. But so far as I know, they're only ever used in the 'negative' sense of "too much of a bad thing". Certainly not "even more of a good thing", which is what OP seems to want.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't think exceeding and surpassing imply positive connotation (*radiation limits were surpassed / radiation exceeded limits*). For exceedance you will find the same if you look at the books http://books.google.com/books?id=neT6jVyMtlIC&pg=PA189&dq=exceedance&hl=en&ei=6CP6Tf_WDMeD-wbCm_nAAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=exceedance&f=false (Sure, it is mostly used when certain limit are exceeded, which if a maximum of something is regulated is not a good thing)

Comment: @Unreason: I don't get you. I'm specifically claiming that **exceedence** is *always* a bad thing. Which is why it's no use for OP's context, since he seems to be talking about something being *better* because it has 'more' of some desirable quality.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, maybe I am a bit slow these days, but I hoped to show that 1) exceedence is not always a bad thing (by quoting usage) 2) quoted OP that he needs it for "test reports and (snip)" where OP does not look for "positive" term, just neutral

Comment: @Unreason: Well I just glanced through a few dozen GoogleBooks entries for *exceedence*, and all of those with an obvious context were about breaching maximum/recommended limits. Maybe it was a bit gung-ho to infer *always negative* from that casual 'mini-survey', and maybe just because OP used the word *surpassing* doesn't mean he definitely wants a *positive* word. Whatever - OP's clearly not a native English speaker, and there's no single 'non-gerund' word in commom parlance to meet the request anyway, so I don't think this question is going much further.

Answer (score 3):

According to quite a few dictionaries [exceedance](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exceedance?show=0&t=1308160162) is a word.

Here are some of the results of the search for its [synonyms](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/synonyms/exceedance) (not gerunds):

- excess
- overrun
- overshoot
- overhang
- overflow

Comment: I reconsidered *exceedance* after reading some other of the dictionary definitions, including the M-W and the business dictionary you linked to.  (The first ones I choose seemed less clear on this point.)  I agree, *exceedance* is the correct word.

Answer (score 2):

"Transcendence" might work for you, if you don't mind the minor New Agey connotations it can have in certain contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Although it has been overused almost to the point of banality, *excellence* means literally "[the fact or state of excelling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/excellence)," and in turn, to *excel* means "[to surpass](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/excel)."

Comment: You might also consider [excess](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/excess); and as others have said, [exceedance](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exceedance) is in dictionaries as well.

Comment: +1 because you're quite right, *and* because you only put up one suggestion in your actual answer. btw - just because *exceedance* is in some dictionaries (*exceedence* in others) doesn't mean it's relevant to this question. See my comment against the question itself.

Comment: +1 *excellence* or *excellency* is the correct answer, depending on context.

Comment: I see your point, but I have a feeling that *excellence* talks about the state (of excelling, superiority; eminence), not an act or event. I don't think that the meaning from the example: "his *excellence* in mathematics", carries over into "his *excellence* of limits(/tresholds/expectations)" that (as I understand it) OP requests.

Comment: @Unreason, I think you're right about the distinction between _acts_ and _states_, but there is some semantic overlap between the two, such that _excellence_ may still be applicable. I think we need more context from the OP to be certain.

Comment: @Unreason There's no need to try and shoehorn the word into a particular construction. Consider: "Our profits exceeded expectations. This excellence was quite remarkable." or "This grade of steel surpasses the tensile strength required to build the structure. Its excellency was determined by an experiment which… blah blah"

Answer (score 0):

The word I might use is **overage.** This usually refers to an excess quantity of goods, but could also refer to excess "performance."

A similar world in this vein is **overachievement.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you could say: outperformance

Comment: Answers are expected to be lengthy. A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.